# In which layer, Are we suppose to place custom repository or data layers or external services interface?

Tags: helix

I m trying to understand Helix framework /Habitat project and I'm mapping the implementation with my current application. We got service layers(that calls web api or restful services) which get all business logic related data. Should we prefer adding such modules in foundation layer or create separate layer for this?

Comment: You might also want to check answers to this question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14762/sitecore-helix-pattern-and-where-to-place-your-business-logic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's used by a single feature, I would say it should be defined in that feature.

If it's used a by number of features, then a Foundation module is probably more appropriate.